# Read Double to vector from hex array

Tags: c++

I was using fread to read data from a file using below code

```
vector<double> table;
table.resize(10);
fread(&table[0],table.size()*sizeof(double), 1, fp);
```

But now I have my data in an array with hex value

Like

`const unsigned char data[] = {0x50,0x11,0x12,......};`

I  know the index from where to read the data,

say `int Index = 100;`

Then how can I read data of type double  from input array and fill the vector?

Comment: It's much similar as with from the file, just `reinterpret_cast<double*>(&data[100]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is with the old C mem* functions:

```
memcpy(&table[0], &data[Index], table.size() * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Don't the source and destination types have to match for that? I think OP is essentially asking about type punning. EDIT: Oh, the reinterpret_cast thing. That'll get you into trouble with alignment when the compiler decides it likes SSE.

Comment: Well, you can use a cast. That would make it clearer what's actually done.

Comment: Yes, cast the source pointer and use copy, is clearest and prevents sizeof from being needed.

Comment: Gah, ninja edit gone awry. I expect alignment trouble. See edit to previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a memory stream around the data, so the same code that deserializes can work on an open file, memory, or any stream at all.